# Why my merge sort implementation give correct result with list but give different (wrong) result when using on numpy array?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, data-structures, mergesort

Here is my implementation on Python

```
def merge(L, R, A):
    len_L = len(L)
    len_R = len(R)

    i = 0 # index for left array L
    j = 0 # index for right array R
    k = 0 # index for main array A

    # replace element in main array A with smaller value from either L or R
    while (i < len_L and j < len_R):
        if L[i] < R[j]:
            A[k] = L[i]
            i+=1
        else:
            A[k] = R[j]
            j+=1
        k+=1

    # replace the rest of main array A with the remianing element from either L or R
    while i < len_L:
        A[k] = L[i]
        i+=1
        k+=1
    while j < len_R:
        A[k] = R[j]
        j+=1
        k+=1

def merge_sort(A):
    if len(A) > 1: # if the element is still dividable (length > 1)
        mid_point = len(A) // 2

        L = A[:mid_point]
        R = A[mid_point:]
        

        merge_sort(L) 
        merge_sort(R)
        merge(L, R, A)
```

when I run this code snippet

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
sample_array = np.arange(21)
np.random.shuffle(sample_array)
print('Unsorted array:', sample_array)
merge_sort(sample_array)
print('Sorted array:', sample_array)
```

I got this result

```
Unsorted array: [ 0 17 15  1  8  5 11  3 18 16 13  2  9 20  4 12  7 10 14 19  6]
Sorted array: [0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 6 6 6 6 6 6]
```

I thought that my implementation is wrong, but in the end I tried to convert it to the list first

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
sample_array = list(np.arange(21))
np.random.shuffle(sample_array)
print('Unsorted array:', sample_array)
merge_sort(sample_array)
print('Sorted array:', sample_array)
```

and suddenly my code works as expected

```
Unsorted array: [0, 17, 15, 1, 8, 5, 11, 3, 18, 16, 13, 2, 9, 20, 4, 12, 7, 10, 14, 19, 6]
Sorted array: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

I wonder what causes this behaviour, I tried to debug a little bit but got no luck. Anyone can enlighten me?

Comment: Key point: when `A` is a list, `L = A[:mid_point]` creates a new list, but when `A` is an `np.array`, `A[:mid_point]` creates a view into the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy slices are views into the original array, while list slices give you a new, independent list.

Consider:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

b = a[:3]
b[1] = 100

print(a)
# array([  1, 100,   3,   4,   5]) <- mutated
```

vs:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

b = a[:3]
b[1] = 100

print(a)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] <- unchanged
```

This has a major impact on your code which is depending on the slice allocating a new list.